# Grub Customizer missing from Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I am not able to install `grub-customizer` in Ubuntu 22.04. Is there any other GUI alternatives for `grub-customizer` or is there any way to install `grub-customizer`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grub Customizer has logic issue that could cause problems. In my case, after editing the text of Ubuntu entry in boot menu, manually add Kernel parameters by editing '/etc/default/grub' will no longer work, even after removed grub-customizer. I have to continue using the tool for the configurations.

Simon Chopin has explained in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-customizer/+bug/1969353):

> However, there are some customizations that are apparently not doable
> by simply editing the existing configuration scripts. For those, the
> program moves all existing conf scripts out of the way, and instead
> installs "proxy scripts" written in a custom language that basically
> filter the output of the original scripts. The language interpreter is
> a standard ELF binary with standard dynamic linking, which seems to
> need the whole Qt stack for some reason. Said interpreter is copied to
> /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy, presumably so that the system keeps
> working even if the user uninstalls grub-customizer.
>
> That logic is actually broken, since removing the grub-customizer
> package might lead to the removal of its dependencies, e.g. the Qt
> stack, leading to a broken binary.

So `grub-customizer` is completely removed from Ubuntu 22.04 repository. via: [ubuntuhandbook](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-2204/)

As @krumpelstiltskin answered, the software developer has updated the app and claimed that the bug mentioned above has been fixed. It's now available in [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edanielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer).

Comment: For future sake, the answer being referred to is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1405761/680629)

Answer (score 2):

Grub customizer is available via the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edanielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer). Follow the instructions therein.

Answer (score 0):

Grub-Customizer package is not available for Ubuntu 22.10 or Ubuntu 23.04 and it doesn't install even using terminal commands.
For all the broken kernel entries leftover from old Ubuntu versions canot be deleted using Sudo apt autoremove or purge as those kernels are not installed. Even apt purge linux-img-unsigned-5.* was ineffectuve.
It shows the error message that package is not installed.
You can install it and then you are able to remove it. For some kernels it works. For kernel 5.15.0-33 and kernel 5.4.0-42 nothing worked.
Following steps cleaned the grub menu entries:

1. sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Sudo apt-get auto clean

Sudo apt-get clean
It is to clean the deprecated software ppas.

2. Remove the broken kernel entries by using

   Sudo rm /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-33*

   Sudo rm /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42*

Also remove the System map and configure files Using remove command like

Sudo rm /boot/System-map-5.15*

Sudo rm /boot/configure-5.15*

3. copy the grub entries file by

Sudo cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg grubBackup.cfb12

or any suitable name for back up of grub in case you need it to restore the Grub. Restore it if you need it by using

Sudo cp /boot/grub/grubBackup.cfg12 grub.cfg

4. Remove menu entry from grub.cfg using

Sudo gnome-text-editor /boot/grub/grub.cfg

for kernels 5.15.0-33 and 5.4.0-42.

Save the grub.cfg file now and close the text editor.

5. update lists by

Sudo apt update

and update grub also

Sudo update-grub

Last action is to ugrade the system also by using

Sudo apt upgrade

Hope it would solve the problem of broken and residual menu entries of Ubuntu 23.04 grub.

Comment: Since 23.04 does not exist yet having this in the quest pushes it to off topic. Please remove any mention of beta products.

Comment: We already have the package information from the 23.04 default repositories, so there's no need to remove it.

Comment: Old Ubuntu versions.  Yes, these have traditionally been manually removed.  This is a separate partition and a specific mount point (/boot). So installing a new OS can leave these whilst destroying what created them. We generally run sudo update-grub afterwards.