# Hibernate not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hibernate

I am using the following system specs:

- Dual boot: Ubuntu 22.04, Windows 11
- BIOS Secure boot is disabled
- Ubuntu is up to date
- I'm using grub-customizer to organize the dual boot.

I'm trying to set hibernate process to my computer. I've followed all the steps in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1241902/76332

But it always start with fresh desktop(Doesn't continue with my working softwares). I've made a deep search and confronted this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404689/76332

I checked the Boot sequence of Ubuntu on the grub customizer and here it's:

```
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a3a6ac41-09fc-452e-b681-afeee519a4bd
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic root=UUID=a3a6ac41-09fc-452e-b681-afeee519a4bd ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-58-generic
```

My /etc/default/grub is that:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
    GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
    GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
    GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=4dea0d66-e4cf-46e7-b728-2981e2b72972"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
    GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080,auto"
    GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub/themes/tela/theme.txt"
```

I couldn't understand what am I missing?

Comment: 22.04 uses a swapfile not a swap partition. To make a swapfile work for hibernation on 22.04 you need to add `resume_offset` when editing `/etc/default/grub`. See my answer a little lower on your first link: https://askubuntu.com/a/1312421/43926

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, that also doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, there are some conflict between ubuntu default grub and grub-customizer

Comment: You may be right, in 15 years of using Ubuntu I have never used grub-customizer. Why do you need it?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron well, then you're a professional Ubuntu user. grub-customizer helps to the ones at the beginner level like me.