# Does regenerating GRUB configuration reset the changes made using GRUB customizer?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 23.04, windows-11

I want to change the order of the boot entries, and therefore I'm thinking to use GRUB customizer. But here is the thing: If I change the order of the boot entries (not the default boot option), and then regenerate GRUB configuration (e.g. with `sudo update-grub`), will it reset the changes (changing order of the boot entries) I made using GRUB customizer?

Also, is there any alternative way to change the order of the boot entries, without editing the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file or setting a default boot option?

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 and Windows 11 (dual boot).

Comment: If you're concerned about messing something up by editing `grub.cfg` then definitely don't use grub-customizer. It was removed from Ubuntu repositories [for good reason](https://askubuntu.com/q/1404445). GRUB is a low level utility that runs before any other parts of the operating system have even been loaded. Grub customizer excessively complicates an essential startup mechanic that isn't designed for the bells and whistles and eye candy it tries to implement. If you want to make customizations, learn to edit `grub.cfg` and keep it simple

Comment: Order of boot entries in UEFI or grub menu? And what change do you want. Typically you can add your own custom boot stanzas into 40_custom so at bottom of menu. But you can copy 40_custom to 06_custom and have your entries at beginning of menu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen & 
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config